# How to find the number of Occupied grids in RTAB-Map global map?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get the total number of grids and the number of occupied grids from the final global map in RTAB-Map?
In the RTAB-Map code there are variables that can list these numbers for each local map, however I need these numbers for the final global map.

PS: I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 VM. RTAB-Map version: 0.19.6

Best regards,
Malar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356340/how-to-find-the-number-of-occupied-grids-in-rtab-map-global-map?/) by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you subscribe to [/rtabmap/grid](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) message, you could count each cell of each type directly.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) on 2020-07-12**:
Thank you @matlabbe